# how to access javascript variable in scriplet jsp

Tags: java, javascript

I have a `javascript variable` say,

```
var a ='2013-01-03'
```

I want to access this variable inside my `scriptlet`. i.e.] I have a `map` that contains my data.
I want to fetch the value of the `map` corresponding to the `key='2013-01-03'` that is in `javascript variable 'a'`.

How can i use like following in my scriptlet.?

```
map.get(a);
```

I know the `scriptlets` will execute first even then without `reloading` I want to access the `variable` a inside my `scriptlet`. Can any one help me solve this problem.?

Comment: Yes it is possible..If you provide some your code, I will try to do that

Comment: why this down vote for this question

Answer (score 1):

You need to submit client data (javascript) to the server (servlets, jsp).
You can do it without reloading a page using ajax.

Answer (score 0):

You have not mentioned the action for which  to perform operation .Assuming If you are making call on focuslost  then

```
$('#yourdom').blur(function() {
        serverCall;

    });




function serverCall{
        $('#yourdom').val('2013-01-03')

            $('#form').submit();


    }
```

In servlet

```
String value=request.getParameter("yourdom");
request.setAttribute("test",value);
RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("your.jsp");  
  rd.forward(request,response);
```

In jsp

```
<% request.getAttribute("test")  %>
```